# Pass longList argument to TECDOC webservice from php

Tags: php, arrays, list, soap, soap-client

I am working with project on TECDOC. get known about TECDOC http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/ here.

So on this page http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/test2/index.html 
in the dropdown menu you will find functions **getVehicleByIds()**, **getVehicleByIds2()**, **getVehicleByIds2StringList()** **and getVehicleByIdsStringList()**.

In above functions You will find a **carIds** field which have datatype as ***longList*** (for first two function) or ***StringList*** (for other two functions).

Now I while calling this function from PHP I have to pass arguments of this field in lonlList or StringList datatype which is not available in PHP and yes know generally for this task generally php array is used. But it is not working here.

here is code...

```
<?php
$url ="http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/wsdl/TecdocToCat";
$trace = array('trace' => 1);
$client = new SoapClient($url, $trace);
$request_array = array(
                        'country'=>'pt',
                        'countryUserSetting'=>'CH',
                        'lang'=>'pt',
                        'motorCodes'=>true,
                        'provider'=>'452',
                        'vehicleTerms'=>true,
                        'carIds'=>1116,
                        'passengerCarDetails'=>true
                    );
echo "<pre>";
    $responce = $client->getVehicleByIds($request_array);

print_r($responce);

?>
```

note : there are some documents provided in first link I post. 
please refer **InterfaceCatService.pdf** for each function datatype details study.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the output like below.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [array] => Array
                (
                )

            [empty] => 1
        )

    [status] => 200
    [statusText] => 
)
```

Hello Again,

I have tried with CURL...by using soapclient there is issue with longlist carIds. so we can do with CURL request.

got the below output.

Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [array] => Array
                (
                    [array] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [carId] => 1116
                                    [motorCodes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [array] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [array] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [motorCode] => DZ
                                                        )

```
                                            )

                                        [empty] => false
                                    )

                                [passengerCarDetails] => Array
                                    (
                                        [brakeSystem] => Hidráulico
                                        [constructionType] => três volumes
                                        [cylinder] => 4
                                        [cylinderCapacityCcm] => 1781
                                        [cylinderCapacityLiter] => 180
                                        [fuelType] => Gasolina
                                        [fuelTypeProcess] => Injecção no colector de admissão/carburador
                                        [impulsionType] => Tracção dianteira
                                        [manuName] => AUDI
                                        [modelName] => 80 (89, 89Q, 8A, B3)
                                        [motorType] => Otto
                                        [powerHP] => 112
                                        [powerKW] => 82
                                        [typeName] => 1.8 E
                                        [typeNumber] => 1116
                                        [valves] => 2
                                        [yearOfConstructionFrom] => 198606
                                        [yearOfConstructionTo] => 199108
                                    )

                                [vehicleDetails] => Array
                                    (
                                        [axisConfiguration] => Array
                                            (
                                                [@value] => 
                                                [@attributes] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [nil] => true
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [carId] => 1116
                                        [ccmTech] => 1781
                                        [constructionType] => três volumes
                                        [manuId] => 5
                                        [modId] => 31
                                        [powerHpFrom] => 112
                                        [powerHpTo] => 112
                                        [powerKwFrom] => 82
                                        [powerKwTo] => 82
                                        [tonnage] => Array
                                            (
                                                [@value] => 
                                                [@attributes] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [nil] => true
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [yearOfConstrFrom] => 198606
                                        [yearOfConstrTo] => 199108
                                    )

                                [vehicleTerms] => Array
                                    (
                                        [carId] => 1116
                                        [carType] => 1.8 E
                                        [manuId] => 5
                                        [manuName] => AUDI
                                        [modId] => 31
                                        [modelName] => 80 (89, 89Q, 8A, B3)
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [carId] => 1117
                                [motorCodes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [array] => Array
                                            (
                                                [array] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [motorCode] => SD
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [empty] => false
                                    )

                                [passengerCarDetails] => Array
                                    (
                                        [brakeSystem] => Hidráulico
                                        [constructionType] => três volumes
                                        [cylinder] => 4
                                        [cylinderCapacityCcm] => 1847
                                        [cylinderCapacityLiter] => 180
                                        [fuelType] => Gasolina
                                        [fuelTypeProcess] => Injecção no colector de admissão/carburador
                                        [impulsionType] => Tracção dianteira
                                        [manuName] => AUDI
                                        [modelName] => 80 (89, 89Q, 8A, B3)
                                        [motorType] => Otto
                                        [powerHP] => 113
                                        [powerKW] => 83
                                        [typeName] => 1.8
                                        [typeNumber] => 1117
                                        [valves] => 2
                                        [yearOfConstructionFrom] => 198609
                                        [yearOfConstructionTo] => 198807
                                    )

                                [vehicleDetails] => Array
                                    (
                                        [axisConfiguration] => Array
                                            (
                                                [@value] => 
                                                [@attributes] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [nil] => true
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [carId] => 1117
                                        [ccmTech] => 1847
                                        [constructionType] => três volumes
                                        [manuId] => 5
                                        [modId] => 31
                                        [powerHpFrom] => 113
                                        [powerHpTo] => 113
                                        [powerKwFrom] => 83
                                        [powerKwTo] => 83
                                        [tonnage] => Array
                                            (
                                                [@value] => 
                                                [@attributes] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [nil] => true
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [yearOfConstrFrom] => 198609
                                        [yearOfConstrTo] => 198807
                                    )

                                [vehicleTerms] => Array
                                    (
                                        [carId] => 1117
                                        [carType] => 1.8
                                        [manuId] => 5
                                        [manuName] => AUDI
                                        [modId] => 31
                                        [modelName] => 80 (89, 89Q, 8A, B3)
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [empty] => false
    )
```

)

Below is the code to get response using CURL.

```
$soap_request  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
$soap_request .= '<soapenv:Envelope     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://path-    to/schemas" xmlns:urn="urn:axis.server.cat.tecdoc.net"     xmlns:car="http://carselection.datatype.tocinterface.cat.tecdoc.net"     xmlns:dat="http://datatype.cat.tecdoc.net"     xmlns:tec="http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/services/TecdocToCatWL">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:getVehicleByIds>
     <urn:in0>
        <car:carIds>
           <dat:array>
              <tec:item>1116</tec:item>
              <tec:item>1117</tec:item>
           </dat:array>
        </car:carIds>
        <car:country>pt</car:country>
        <car:countryUserSetting>CH</car:countryUserSetting>
        <car:lang>pt</car:lang>
        <car:motorCodes>true</car:motorCodes>
        <car:passengerCarDetails>true</car:passengerCarDetails>
        <car:provider>292</car:provider>
        <car:vehicleTerms>true</car:vehicleTerms>
</urn:in0>
</urn:getVehicleByIds>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$header = array(
"Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Pragma: no-cache",
"SOAPAction: \"run\"",
"Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
```

);

```
$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-    0/services/TecdocToCatWL?wsdl" );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_PROXY, IF_ANY);

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
```

Thanks,
Gaurang

Comment: it shold not be return empty array. [data] must contains car details results. check this [link] http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/test2/index.html 

select **vehicleByids** function and submit it manually by feeling same data in form.

Comment: http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/doc/guide.html 
In above link they have suggested alternative function for **getVehicleByIds** with **getVehicleByIdsStringList** (PHP) . which is also not supporting.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the array to tecdoc list type.

Its very easy though, make a `stdClass` object with 2 fields.

`empty` and `array`

set `empty` to false and `array` to the array of carIds like

```
$carIds = array(1116);
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->empty = false;
$obj->array = $carIds;
```

now pass $obj in the params list of soap request

```
$request_array = array(

                    'country'=>'pt',
                    'countryUserSetting'=>'CH',
                    'lang'=>'pt',
                    'motorCodes'=>true,
                    'provider'=>'292',
                    'vehicleTerms'=>true,
                    'carIds'=> $obj,
                    'passengerCarDetails'=>true
                );
```

better make a function which converts the array to above object structure, the `empty` flag will be set to true if `array` is null or empty